# Combining two SQL queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two sql queries (which both work independently) that I am trying to combine:

Query #1:

```
select 
    N1."DateAndTime",
    N0."Ration" 
from 
    (("dbo"."AnimalFeedDailyConsumption" N0 
inner join 
    "dbo"."AnimalHistoricalData" N1 on (N0."OID" = N1."OID")) 
left join 
    "dbo"."BasicAnimal" N2 on (N1."BasicAnimal" = N2."OID"))
where 
    (N1."LactationNumber" = 4) and (N1."GCRecord" is null and (N2."Number" = 511))
```

Query #2:

```
select 
   N2."Number",
   N1."DIM",
   N1."DateAndTime",
   N1."LactationNumber",
   N0."TotalYield"
from 
   (("dbo"."DailyMilk" N0 
inner join 
   "dbo"."AnimalHistoricalData" N1 on (N0."OID" = N1."OID")) 
left join 
   "dbo"."BasicAnimal" N2 on (N1."BasicAnimal" = N2."OID"))
where 
   (N1."LactationNumber" = 4) and (N1."GCRecord" is null and (N2."Number" = 511))
```

I tried this which resulted in nulls for 'Ration':

```
select 
    N2."Number",
    N1."DIM",
    N1."DateAndTime",
    N1."LactationNumber",
    N0."TotalYield",
    N3."Ration"
from 
    (("dbo"."DailyMilk" N0 
inner join 
    "dbo"."AnimalHistoricalData" N1 on (N0."OID" = N1."OID")) 
left join 
    ("dbo"."AnimalFeedDailyConsumption" N3 
inner join 
    "dbo"."AnimalHistoricalData" N1 on (N3."OID" = N1."OID"))
left join 
    "dbo"."BasicAnimal" N2 on (N1."BasicAnimal" = N2."OID"))
where 
    (N1."LactationNumber" = 4) and (N1."GCRecord" is null and (N2."Number" = 511))
```

So then I tried this which also resulted in nulls for 'Ration':

```
select 
   N2."Number",
   N1."DIM",
   N1."DateAndTime",
   N1."LactationNumber",
   N0."TotalYield",
   N3."Ration"
from
   (("dbo"."DailyMilk" N0 
inner join 
   "dbo"."AnimalHistoricalData" N1 on (N0."OID" = N1."OID")) 
left join 
   "dbo"."AnimalFeedDailyConsumption" N3 on (N3."OID" = N1."OID")
left join 
   "dbo"."BasicAnimal" N2 on (N1."BasicAnimal" = N2."OID"))
where 
   (N1."LactationNumber" = 4) and (N1."GCRecord" is null and (N2."Number" = 511))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer because I don't know the relationships between your tables. In your "working" queries, you are testing for conditions on the RIGHT table (N2), which you joined with LEFT OUTER because it is optional - perhaps this is correct, but doesn't look right.

How about this, with all joins converted to inner joins?:

```
select 
  N2."Number",
  N1."DIM",
  N1."DateAndTime",
  N1."LactationNumber",
  N0."TotalYield",
  N3."Ration"
from "dbo"."DailyMilk" N0 
inner join "dbo"."AnimalHistoricalData" N1       on N0."OID" = N1."OID" 
inner join "dbo"."AnimalFeedDailyConsumption" N3 on N3."OID" = N1."OID"
inner join "dbo"."BasicAnimal" N2                on N1."BasicAnimal" = N2."OID"
where N1."LactationNumber" = 4 
and   N1."GCRecord" is null 
and   N2."Number" = 511
```

*Style Comment:* BTW it is hard (for me) to understand which table is N0, N1, N3 & N3. Why not alias them as BA, AHD, DM and AFDC? Also, too many (redundant) braces.

Note: I can't test this out since I don't have your tables or data. How about you create a SQLfiddle?

Comment: Thank you Turophile. With all joins as inner joins the query returns no errors but also no data. Wish I could create a SQLfiddle but the database is massive, was not created by me and I am just a beginner at sql.

Comment: Well the query I provided will return everything in the tables that relates by the joins, but filtered by the `WHERE` conditions. So, try running the query with one condition removed, then with one of the other conditions removed, etc to see what impact each condition has. You can do the same with each table - in case one of the joins is incorrect and results in no matches - this is how I would debug the query. Also look at your tables' data and manually check each of the joins to ensure OID in one is the same OID in another.

Comment: Note that if `OID` is in three tables, it should only be the PK in one - the other two will be a FK and therefore not unique.

Comment: Here is a fiddle to experiment on - note that it gets results from your first two queries, and from mine. So The data setup must not match yours. That may be a clue. I suspect the problem lies with the keys/foreign keys of the tables OID & BasicAnimal. The Fiddle :: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c9f5f/1